# Problem signing BlackBerry apps

Tags: blackberry, code-signing

I'm making web based applications for BlackBerry using the PhoneGap Framework. I got 3 .CSI key files from the BlackBerry Dev-Center and signed my applications, but when I try to install an application in BlackBerry I get an error with information about signing.

Maybe I am having a problem with signing?

What is the best way to sign applications for Blackberry? Note that I'm not using Eclipse because it has some errors on my computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions you were provided would've been the best way to do code signing. If you've lost them, they're on page 8 in [How and when to sign](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/Testing_and_Deployment_of_Applications@tkb/118/1/How_And_When_To_Sign_V2.pdf).

You do not have to put your apps in App World to share them; however, you would lose the marketing and ease-of-access benefits that BB App world provides.

Comment: Thanks. I understand, that I can share apps without appworld, but I still can't sign apps, because I don't use Eclipse (I'm getting some errors). I develop in Dreamweaver CS 5.5

Comment: Can you explain what errors you're getting and how you're trying to sign your apps?

Comment: I requested new sign keys from Blackberry and after with new keys everything is ok. Seems it was problem with old keys. Thanks for help.